# What is the wrong with this code?

Tags: java, numbers

```
String phrase = "4556.44";
Float num = new Float(phrase);
int dollars = (int) Math.floor(num);
System.out.println(""+dollars);
int cent = (int) Math.floor((num - dollars) * 100.0F);
int cent2 =  (int) ((num - dollars) * 100.0);
System.out.println(""+cent+":"+cent2);
```

This is a Number to Word Class Code Phrase, My Problem is when I run this code fragment the output result is `4556.43`. But the input value is `4556.44`. Please tell me why this is happened and I need the answer for correct this Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int cent = (int)(num * 100f % 100f);
```

Comment: hi,Thanks for all .your Code is working for me Thank you.triple gems bless you

Answer (score 2):

For high precision calculations with controlled rounding use `BigDecimal` instead `Float`

Answer (score 1):

Floats are less precise than doubles which are less precise than BigDecimal.

When working with programmes that absolutely must be precise (like financial applications) use a BigDecimal.

If this is a small homework and non-critical app you can try out Double to see if it is precise enough for you.

Comment: I believe you meant double when you said long.

Answer (score 0):

`Float` is not a good choice for precision calculations.

```
 int cent = (int) Math.floor((num - dollars) * 100.0F);
```

above statement in the code doesn't exactly give you precise answers as you would expect.

Try using `Double` or `BigInteger` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Floats and Doubles cannot represent all possible real numbers, since they use a [specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754%3a_floating_point_in_modern_computers) that makes up numbers by adding any of the following numbers: 1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 etc...

If you try out `0.1f+0.1f+0.1f==0.3f` you'll get false. So, as other people said, use BigDecimal, it uses a different representation, it's much slower, but it won't incur in these problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following

```
String phrase = "4556.44";
long money = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(phrase) * 100);
long dollars = money / 100;
long cents = money % 100;
System.out.printf("%,d dollars and %d cents%n", dollars, cents);
```

prints

```
4,556 dollars and 44 cents
```